# Where are the compiled files?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular project in VS Code created by yeoman (`yo start-angular`). I believe the project is running on some lite-server.

The app runs fine. However, I can't locate where the compiled html and Javascript files are. Where in the file system are they?

Comment: Are you using grunt commands to compile the files ?

Comment: I guess it's using `ng serve` behind the scenes, meaning that the files are in memory and not written to disk. With Angular-CLI, files are compiled in the `./dist` folder by default when you do `ng build`, but with Yeoman I don't know.

Comment: https://github.com/seesharprun/generator-start-angular

Comment: @PunitaOjha Actually I don't know how the compilation is done. I simply pressed F5 in Code and it ran. What're the steps to trace the compilation process?